# Any way to execute the schema.sql (or concrete schema-postgres.sql) after "schema from model" creation?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Is there any way to tell the Spring Boot to execute its `schema.sql` or in my case `schema-postgres.sql` **after** creating the database model from object model?

The relevant part of my `application.properties` looks like that

```
spring.datasource.platform: postgresql

spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

In my `schema-postgres.sql` I define a view on two of the tables specified by my object model.

Of course when the app is started for the first time there are no tables in the schema yet and Spring Boot tries to execute `schema-postgres.sql` before creating the actual schema, which as the result ends with an error.

I could not find anything in the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) on it.

Comment: FWIW JPA 2.1 provides standard properties allowing create of a schema/tables and loading up of data.

Comment: I guess this is why there are two files possible in Spring Boot `schema.sql` and `data.sql`. Creating a view though is not DML but DDL, therefore I am not sure whether it should be the part of `data.sql`. Have I understood you correctly? Are you suggesting putting this definition of a view into `data.sql`?